# Summarize by gpt with output has text and original images

Tags: nlp, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using OpenAI API (based on [langchain](https://www.langchain.com/)) to do a task of summarizing serials of PDF files into a single PDF file.

By using `pdfreader` I can parse and construct pdf files, and by gpt I can easily get summarized text.

The questions is, the source pdf files contains images, some of them are crucial for understanding the overall content, thus I want the summarized content from gpt is **not just text**, but with the **key images from original** pdf files, does gpt support this ?